# Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found

Tags: php

Подскажите, что делать: залил на хост сайт и выдает мне вот это.

> `Warning: include(Cake/bootstrap.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u611215527/public_html/app/webroot/index.php on line 77`
>
> `Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Cake/bootstrap.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/u611215527/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/u611215527/public_html/app/webroot/index.php on line 77`
>
> `Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your /cake core directory and your /vendors root directory. in /home/u611215527/public_html/app/webroot/index.php on line 86`

Сперва вообще выдавало ошибку сервера 500 ,прописал в файле Htacces RewriteBase / и стало отображать вот эти ошибки,уже перечитал кучу статей ничего не помогает

Comment: сначала установите фреймворк.  
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP

Comment: А как бы я писал проект на кейке без установленного фреймворка?

Comment: > залил на хост сайт

    локалхост != хост
Поэтому логично предположить, что фреймворк не установлен.

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто. Рядом с `/home/u611215527/public_html/app/webroot/index.php` должна лежать папка Cake, а в ней bootstap.php.

Comment: Shurik спасибо большое ща попробую!